# how to send image in byteArray with parameters in JSON format iOS swift4

Tags: ios, http-post, alamofire, swift4, image-uploading

I am a beginner to iOS and I am having a only a lot less knowledge on programming. Now, in my project I got stuck with a task where I have to send the data of a user being created along with the uploading image for camera or from photo library. Actually I don't know how to do that, I have searched the internet, stackoverflow & some other blogs on how to send images with parameters in swift4 and trying to understand the process still and I have been trying this for a week I don't know what else to do. I am posting my code Here:

```
 @IBAction func createAccountTapped(_sender: UIButton!) {

        guard let image = profileImgView.image else {return}

        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7)
        print(imageData!)

        let byteArray = Array(imageData!)

        let updateProfileUrl = "http://isit.beetlerim.com/api/UsersAPI/UpdateUserProfile"

        let parameters = [
            "UserName":userNameTF.text!,
            "Password":passwordTF.text!,
            "UserTypeId":2,
            "profilePic":"\(arc4random()).jpg",
            "profileImage":byteArray,
            "DOB":dateOfBirthTF.text!,
            "PhoneNumber":phoneNumberTF.text!,
            "Mobile":phoneNumberTF.text!,
            "Email":emailAddressTF.text!,
            "AddressLine1":address1TF.text!,
            "AddressLine2":address2TF.text!,
            "City":cityTF.text!,
            "State":stateTF.text!,
            "Country":countryTF.text!,
            "ZipCode":zipcodeTF.text!
            ] as [String : Any]

        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)

        print(jsonData!)

        // create post request
        let url = URL(string: updateProfileUrl)!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        // insert json data to the request
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accpet")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
                return
            }
            let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments )
            if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
                print(responseJSON)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
```

I am getting responseJSON : ["message":An error has occurred.]
}

I have tried many other ways also.. none of them worked neither.. 
please help me guys:

Comment: The error message clearly says _'multipart/form-data' is not supported_, and you still try with `multipartFormData`? Better check the API spec.

Comment: @OOper can you please explain, how to send image with parameters in application/json format..

Comment: We need to set in http header content type of image i.e png or jpeg

Comment: @VIP-DEV I did it there as `headers: ["Content-Type" : "application/json"]`,  still no result..

Comment: @OOper I am wondering if I can ask our server side developers what kind of data they are accepting, and make sure I am sending it that way..

Comment: @OOper they asked me to send the image with parameters in json format. But, everywhere in the internet I can only see `multipart/form-data` for this scenario

Comment: There are servers which takes images in JSON, usually base64 or sometimes hex. (Including huge data in JSON is, in my opinion, a bad design. Better find better server side engineers.) Assuming base64, seeing your `parameters`, which already include the line `"profilePic": base64String,`, you just need to use a usual Alamofire request than `upload(multipartFormData:)`. I have never used Alamofire in my apps, but I think you can do it yourself or someone can help if you update your question including that _they asked me to send the image with parameters in json format_.

Comment: @OOper thanks for the reply mate, it is very helpful. And my server side engineer are asking to send the image in byteArray not in base64String. I am thinking that `let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImgView.image!, 0.7)` this line of code converts it into byteArray..Not sure though..

Comment: Byte array in JSON... Incredible... `imageData` in your code becomes `Data?`, not _byte array_. In c#, _byte array_ is equivalent to Swift `Array<UInt8>`, you can make it with `let byteArray = Array(imageData!)`. In Java _byte array_, Swift `Array<Int8>`, a little bit more complicated: `let byteArray = Array(imageData!.lazy.map{Int8(bitPattern: $0)})`. There may be some possible cases, but only knows your server side engineers.

Comment: @OOper I did as you said, But when I try to send the image I am getting success message as ["message": An error has occurred.]. I don't know what I am doing wrong.. I will edit my question.

Comment: Seems I just have to repeat: _only knows your server side engineers._ As you see the error message has no info about the error. The json is generated by the server, not by your code nor by iOS.

Comment: Your question lacks some important info. _'multipart/form-data' is not supported_. _they asked me to send the image with parameters in json format_. _my server side engineer are asking to send the image in byteArray not in base64String_. Not many readers read long lasting comments.

Comment: @OOper Thank you so much for guiding me in this process.. I learned something new form you and "Aaoli".. They asked me to send in byte[], but it didn't work.. but I gave a try for the "Aaoli" way, sending it in base64. God! it worked.. looks like our server side engineers have no idea what they are doing... Anyway, Thank you so much guys.

Comment: Happy to hear that you have found a solution. One thing you should note that, even if sometimes server side engineers use wrong terminology, it is very important to communicate with sever side people to write a right communication code. Good luck.

Comment: @OOper Sure thing bro.. Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to insure that the image size is less than the maximum from the server side and that’s one way that the server might be telling you but still you’ll need to debug it with server side. let’s say mostly it’s limited to be 2 MB as max usually.

So you’ll need to first resize it and then convert it to base64 but this is not preferred way of uploading images because it increases the size of the data transferred by 33%. Server side should use `multipart/form-data` because it’s the standard way of transferring binary data over HTTP. But here you go:

```
let imageResized = image.resizeWith(percentage: 0.1)
let base64 = imageResized?.toBase64()
```

You’ll need to use the following extensions:

```
extension UIImage {
    func resizeWith(percentage: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: size.width * percentage, height: size.height * percentage)))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = self
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, false, scale)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        imageView.layer.render(in: context)
        guard let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return nil }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return result
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    
    func toBase64() -> String? {
        
        let imageData : NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 1.0)! as NSData
        return imageData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)
    }
}
```

Finally send your parameter this way:

```
let parameters = [
            "UserName":userNameTF.text!,
            "Password":passwordTF.text!,
            "UserTypeId":2,
            "profilePic":"\(arc4random()).png",
            "profileImage":base64!,
            "DOB":dateOfBirthTF.text!,
            "PhoneNumber":phoneNumberTF.text!,
            "Mobile":phoneNumberTF.text!,
            "Email":emailAddressTF.text!,
            "AddressLine1":address1TF.text!,
            "AddressLine2":address2TF.text!,
            "City":cityTF.text!,
            "State":stateTF.text!,
            "Country":countryTF.text!,
            "ZipCode":zipcodeTF.text!
            ] as [String : Any]
```

Hope this works !

Comment: @Aaoli OMG!!! That's a hell of a string.. it worked..Thanks you so much for this. I will be in your debt...